# produce rpm which show error if some condition not passed

Tags: rpm, specifications, rpmbuild

what exactly I want to do is producing an rpm which checks some condition during installation and if it doesn't pass, show some error and exit from installation. how can I implement it in the spec file?

```
%pre
if [ $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX != "/opt" ]; then
echo " this place is not acceptable. this package will not install"
exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Show us some code from your `.spec` file that you've tried and failed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do these checks during install, values -- particularly from rpm build configuration -- are quite (IMHO, YMMV) predictable.

Instead add logic to check the values during build if you need a sanity check on the build configuration. In many cases you should be able to override required build configuration as well.

E.g. The RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX is set from a (actually multiple, it's an array, not a scalar) Prefix: directive(s) unless overridden with --relocate when installing (which hardly ever happens in practice). Add a Prefix: directive to override, or check the value of %prefix during the build.